# Получить список дат последних модификаций файлов в папке

Tags: perl

Собственно сабж. Опыта с Perl нет никакого. Нужно получить массив с датами последних модификаций всех файлов в конкретной папке. Пока пробую использовать нативные команды ОС и парсить результат, но это видится как костыль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы искать [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)

Чтобы определить является ли найденное обычным файлом [-f](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X)

Чтобы вычислить дату модификации [stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat)

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper qw/Dumper/;

my $d = $ARGV[0] || '.';
my @paths;
find(sub { push @paths, $File::Find::name }, $d);

my @files;
foreach my $f (@paths) {
  if (-f $f) {
    my @f_stat = stat($f);
    push @files, { file => $f, mtime => $f_stat[9] };
  }
}

print Dumper @files;
```

Результат:

```bsh
$ perl src/file-stat-1/index.pl ./src

...
$VAR267 = {
            'mtime' => 1620653004,
            'file' => './src/oracle-2/typeorm.ts'
          };
$VAR268 = {
            'mtime' => 1620653008,
            'file' => './src/oracle-2/oracledb.js'
          };
$VAR269 = {
            'mtime' => 1620653011,
            'file' => './src/oracle-2/knex.js'
          };
$VAR270 = {
            'file' => './src/express-1024-bytes/index.js',
            'mtime' => 1624648857
          };
```

Другие варианты поиска файлов можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1045792/4496422).

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что нужно.

Comment: btw, зачем вам perl, учёба?

Comment: Нет. Получил таск добавить немного функционала в сущестующий дремучий легаси скрипт ))   Нужно успеть за один спринт выучить хоть немного базовый синтаксис и закрыть таск. Остальные действия уже сделал, а вот с файлами была засада.  И еще вопрос, если можно. Где можно посмотреть, что такое и для чего нужена строка use Data::Dumper qw/Dumper/;  ?

Comment: с perlыми модулями всё просто: если написано `use ...` то нужно идти на https://metacpan.org/, найти и читать. если кейс использования не понятен то можно зайти в sources (ссылки слева) и посмотреть в каталоге '/t' (тесты). если информации мало - читать исходники модуля. `Data::Dumper` это как-бы форматер, который отформатирует любой объект в строку, которую будет удобно читать, если распечатаешь (см. "Результат" в ответе). `Data::Dumper` есть на любой машине, так что в ответе я написал именно его. но я предпочитал модуль DDP, он повеселей.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper

Comment: Спасибо. Мне вывод не нужен, я дальше с датами оперирую. Скрипт серверный, там читать некому )))

Comment: а вообще, `use ModuleName` это импорт модуля, https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use